# Can a class self instanciate?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Can a class inherit an unreferenced assembly?  Or can it maybe self-instanciate?

I'd like to be able to dynamically load an unreferenced dll and set it to itself -- Something like:

```
Public Class MyProject.SomeClassWrapper
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.AxHost

    Public Sub New()
        Dim dynamicallyLoadedAssembly As System.Reflection.Assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile("C:\Temp\SomeLibrary.dll")
        Me  = dynamicallyLoadedAssembly.CreateInstance("SomeLibrary.SomeClass") '<----- Doesn't work, but is there a way to do this?            
    End Sub
End Class
```

Or maybe dynamically load a class and inherit it?

```
'This class has the some of the properties/methods/etc as the library being imported
Public Class MyProject.SomeClassWrapper
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.AxHost

    Public Sub New(clsid As String)
        MyBase.New(clsid)
    End Sub

    Public Sub SomeSubroutineHere()
        'Do something
    End Sub
End Class

'This class needs to inherit from a dynamically loaded assembly via reflection
Public Class MyClass
    Inherits MyProject.SomeClassWrapper

    Public Sub New()

        Dim dynamicallyLoadedAssembly As System.Reflection.Assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile("C:\Temp\SomeLibrary.dll")
        Dim newInstance  = dynamicallyLoadedAssembly.CreateInstance("SomeLibrary.SomeClass")
        Dim strCLSID as String = "Where can i get the CLSID from here?"

        MyBase = newInstance '<<< I want to set "MyBase" to the new instance so that when MyBase.New() is called, it's the full inherited library
        MyBase.New(strCLSID)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, you can't do either of these things. Once an object is created (or being created) it cannot change type or instance. VB is a statically-typed language.

Comment: You cannot assign to Me. At all. What are you *really* trying to achieve? Are you loading your own library dynamically, or someone's else? What does the library do and why do you have to load it dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do either of these things. Once an object is created (or being created) it cannot change type or instance. VB is a statically-typed language.

But you can use the decorator pattern to get close.

Try this:

```
Public Interface IDecorator
    Sub DoSomething()
End Interface

Public Class MyDecoratorClass
    Implements IDecorator

    Private _inner As IDecorator

    Public Sub New()
        Dim dynamicallyLoadedAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile("C:\Temp\SomeLibrary.dll")
        Dim newInstance = dynamicallyLoadedAssembly.CreateInstance("SomeLibrary.SomeClass")
        _inner = CType(newInstance, IDecorator) ' `newInstance` must implement `IDecorator`
    End Sub

    Public Sub DoSomething() Implements IDecorator.DoSomething
        _inner.DoSomething()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Now when you call the `IDecorator` methods on `MyDecoratorClass` the actual calls get sent through the dynamically loaded instance.

Comment: Thanks - I'll experiment with this today to see if i can make it work. One question - you said "VB is a statically-typed language". Did you mean .NET or are you implying that it can be done using, say, with c#?

Comment: @Losbear - The question was about VB, so I didn't extend to C#, but it is the same. However, there are plenty of .NET languages that are dynamic and _possibly_ can do what you're after so I couldn't go as far as saying .NET in general.